# How can I add unit test for android architecture components life cycle event?

Tags: android, android-testing, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-lifecycle

I tried to add a unit test for my function which supports architecture components lifecycle event. To support lifecycle event, I added the `@OnLifecycleEvent` annotation for my function which I want to do something when that event occurred.

Everything is working as expected but I want to create a unit test for that function to check my function running when the intended event occurred.

```
 public class CarServiceProvider implements LifecycleObserver {

    public void bindToLifeCycle(LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner) {
        lifecycleOwner.getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    public void onClear() {
       Log.i("CarServiceProvider", "onClear called");
    }
 }
```

I tried to mock LifecycleOwner and create new LifecycleRegistery to change the state of lifecycle observer but I didn't do.

How can I test my `onClear()` function called when state changed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite of I am not a big fan, I would go with [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) making use of [ActivityController](http://robolectric.org/activity-lifecycle/) to achieve this.

Given the fact that the "Observables" of the [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) applied in 
Android Lifecycle workflow are Activities, Fragments... An application context is a must and we need somehow bring it to our test scenario.

I achieved the expected result by doing this

**build.gradle**

```
testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.5.1"
```

**CarServiceProviderTest.java**

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
public class CarServiceProviderTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldFireOnClear(){

        //Grab the Activity controller
        ActivityController controller = Robolectric.buildActivity(JustTestActivity.class).create().start();
        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) controller.get();

        //Instanciate our Observer
        CarServiceProvider carServiceProvider = new CarServiceProvider();
        carServiceProvider.bindToLifeCycle(activity);

        //Fire the expected event
        controller.stop();

        //Assert
        Assert.assertTrue(carServiceProvider.wasFired);
    }
}
```

**CarServiceProvider.java**

```
public class CarServiceProvider implements LifecycleObserver {

    public boolean wasFired;

    public void bindToLifeCycle(LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner) {
        lifecycleOwner.getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    public void onClear() {
        wasFired = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: but how about fragment?  buildFragment doesn' t work

Answer (score 14):

You should be able to use the [LifecycleRegistry](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleRegistry)

Your test would do something like below:

```
@Test
public void testSomething() {
  LifecycleRegistry lifecycle = new LifecycleRegistry(mock(LifecycleOwner.class));

  // Instantiate your class to test
  CarServiceProvider carServiceProvider = new CarServiceProvider();
  carServiceProvider.bindToLifeCycle(lifecycle);

  // Set lifecycle state
  lifecycle.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)

  // Verify that the ON_STOP event was handled, with an assert or similar check
  ...
}
```

If you are testing *Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY* then you probably need to call *handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)* prior to this.

Comment: I don't see how this can work. In your example `lifecycle` is of type `LifecycleRegistry`, but `bindToLifeCycle` takes in a `LifecycleOwner`.

Comment: Well, he would then change the signature of that method, it does `lifecycleOwner.getLifecycle()` anyway so passing a `lifecycle` would probably make sense anyway

Comment: :thumbsup: Right. I didn't see that LifecycleRegistry implements Lifecycle

Answer (score 9):

You can test using Unit tests without Roboletric as long as you mock the lifecycle owner properly.

```
val lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner = Mockito.mock(LifecycleOwner::class.java)
val lifecycle = LifecycleRegistry(Mockito.mock(LifecycleOwner::class.java))
lifecycle.markState(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
Mockito.`when`(lifecycleOwner.lifecycle).thenReturn(lifecycle)
```

Use this lifecycleOwner when you observe a variable and you can use Mockito.verify to see if your callback has been called

Comment: Best solution so far, you could adjust the line which is deprecated:
`lifecycle.currentState = Lifecycle.State.RESUMED`

Comment: In my case this results in a crash
```java
Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the TestLifecycleOwner from the

```
androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-testing
```

dependency

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/testing/TestLifecycleOwner

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on `Raz's` answer, in Kotlin you can make an extension function to make this more reusable.

```
fun LifecycleObserver.testLifeCycleEvent(lifecycleEvent: Lifecycle.Event) {
   val mockLifeCycleOwner: LifecycleOwner = mockk()
   val lifecycleRegistry = LifecycleRegistry(mockLifeCycleOwner)
   lifecycleRegistry.addObserver(this)
   lifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(lifecycleEvent)
}
```

In the original questioner's case, they have a `fun bindToLifecycle()`.  If you are doing something like that, you can just make an extension function for that as well so it applies to all `LifecycleObserver` types:

```
fun LifecycleObserver.bindToLifeCycle(lifecycle: Lifecycle) {
        lifecycle.addObserver(this);
    }
```

and then modify `testLifeCycleEvent()` like this:

```
fun LifecycleObserver.testLifeCycleEvent(lifecycleEvent: Lifecycle.Event) {
   val mockLifeCycleOwner: LifecycleOwner = mockk()
   val lifecycleRegistry = LifecycleRegistry(mockLifeCycleOwner)
   this.bindLifecycle(lifecycleRegistry)
   lifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(lifecycleEvent)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test it with a real Unit test (not AndroidTest), your best bet is to use Robolectric, it mocks the Android framework and Robolectric 4.0 is coming out. However you're trying to test the actual interaction with the Android Framework, so that's a task better suited for a true integration testing suite and an AndroidTest. You can unit test it but the most sure way to test it would be to actually invoke the lifecycle event on a device (What Espresso would do) and verify it's called.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample for Powermock v3.8 and RESUME event. I use this event to show how to verify livedata value

#build.gradle

```
dependencies {
        ...
        testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.8'
        testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.2"
        testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:2.0.2"
        testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.2"
        testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:1.6.4"
        ...
    }
```

#CustomViewModel.kt

```
class CustomViewModel() : ViewModel(), LifecycleObserver {
    private val _outputData = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val outputData: LiveData<Boolean> = _outputData

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
    fun onResume() {
       //TODO action
       outputData.value = true
    }
}
```

#CustomViewModelTest.kt

```
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.mockito.Mock
import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.mockito.Mockito.mock
import org.mockito.Mockito.spy
import org.mockito.Mockito.verify
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PowerMockIgnore
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunnerDelegate
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner::class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@PowerMockIgnore("org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", "androidx.*")
@Config(manifest = Config.NONE)
class CustomViewModelTest {
    @Mock
    lateinit var observer: Observer<in Boolean>

    @Before
    fun beforeTest() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    }

    @Test
    @Config(sdk = [Build.VERSION_CODES.O])
    fun `do an action on resume event`() {
        val vm = spy(CustomViewModel())
        vm.outputData.observeForever(observer)

        vm.testLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)

        verify(vm).onResume()
        verify(observer).onChange(true)
    }
}

fun LifecycleObserver.testLifecycleEvent(lifecycleEvent: Lifecycle.Event) {
    val lifecycleOwner = Mockito.mock(LifecycleOwner::class.java)
    val lifecycleRegistry = LifecycleRegistry(lifecycleOwner)
    this.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleRegistry)
    lifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(lifecycleEvent)
}

fun LifecycleObserver.bindToLifecycle(lifecycle: Lifecycle) {
    lifecycle.addObserver(this)
}
```